# flatpickr + external elements not working

Tags: flatpickr

I am new to flatpickr.

Can someone show in a jsfiddle how the "flatpickr + external elements" works?

I have 4/5 text inputs on the page. I am converting those text inputs to flatpicker using

```
/* flatpickr initialisation */
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.datetime').flatpickr({
            noCalendar: false,
            enableTime: true,
            allowInput: true,
            dateFormat: 'M d, Y h:i K',
            minuteIncrement: 1,

        });
});
```

In my html page, I have html like,
    /* Html page */

```
<input name="endtDate" type="text" class="datetime" placeholder="Select Date.." data-input> 
<a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle>
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
</a>
<a class="input-button" title="clear" data-clear>
    <i class="icon-close"></i>
</a>

....
```

If I do not add **wrap: true** everything works fine.

If I add add **wrap: true** then I got JS errors and flatpickr is not rendering.

Error: invalid input element specified null

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Flatpickr docs don't explain this at all, but what you have to do is "wrap" the elements in another element and pass *that* element to the flatpickr() function.  That's what the "wrap" in "wrap: true" is referring to.

```
<div class="datetime">
    <input name="endtDate" type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." data-input> 
    <a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle>
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="input-button" title="clear" data-clear>
        <i class="icon-close"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```